# How can I export a generic rust function to a C++ header?

Tags: rust, ffi

I want to export a function like
`func<T, T>(T a, T b)`

I get an error saying `no_mangle` attribute can't be added to a generic function.

If this can't be done directly, is there an indirect way to expose a generic function to C?
So far I have not been able to come up with a solution

Comment: This cannot be done. A generic function is _monomorphized_ at compile time. You have to create different wrappers for all the types you want to export.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible, C does not have a concept of "generic functions" and both C++ and Rust monomorphize the functions before linking. As suggested in the comments, you'll have to create wrappers for each pair of types you want to call from C/C++ a macro can help reduce the boilerplate:

```rust
fn func<T, U>(a: T, b: U) { }

macro_rules! manual_mono {
    ($(($t:ty, $u:ty)),* $(,)?) => {
        $(paste::paste!(
        #[no_mangle]
        pub extern fn [< func_ $t _ $u >](a: $t, b: $u) {
            func::<$t, $u>(a, b)
        }
        );)*
    };
}

manual_mono!(
    (i8, i8),
    (i16, i8),
    (i8, i16),
    (i16, i16),
);

fn main() {
    func_i8_i8(0, 1);
    func_i16_i8(0, 1);
    // etc…
}
```